# Error on send an Ajax request to Controller, it isn't going as a json type

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables

I am running Mojave / Laravel 5.8 / PHP 7.2 / Jquery.dataTables 10.1.19.

First round:

If I don't put: `if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('.table')) {...` 

I got this error: **`DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.`** 

I don't know exactly why, but I put this IF and it worked. I have other project where it works without that.

Second round: 

In my index I call `DataTable()` that call an Ajax request to fill the table, so the Ajax URL is a route (from resource, created automatically) to a controller.

In my controller I have a function INDEX who will receive the request, but it needs to be checked if came from an Ajax request (the request must be a JSON) or from a view request.

I don't know why it always got a not Json type.

So, I got this error: **`DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response.`**

**index.blade.php**

```
            <div class="table-responsive">

               <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>NIF</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
            .
            .
            .
            <script type="text/javascript">   
               if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('.table')) {     
                  $('.table').DataTable({
                     "ajax": "{{ route('usuarios.index') }}",
                     "responsive": true,
                     "processing": true,
                     "serverSide": true,
                     "columns": [
                            { "data": "name" },
                            { "data": "nif" },
                            { "data": "email" },
                     ]
                  });
               };
            </script>
```

**UsuariosController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request){ 
   if (request()->wantsJson()) {

       NEVER HERE 

       return ...

    }

    return view('admin.acesso.usuarios.index');
 }
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'acesso'], function () {
    Route::resource('usuarios', "Acesso\UsuariosController");
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you get in suppose to be `json` response?

Comment: The question isn't the json response, but is the initial Ajax request. So, how the function (in controller) don't receive a Request()->wantsJson, it doesn't enter to prepare the json response. I guess there is something wrong or missed on Ajax Request when I initialise DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

**error: DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.**

You cannot reinitialize a data table. you have to destroy it.

```
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#your_table")) {
  $('#mytable').DataTable().clear().destroy();
}

$("#your_table").dataTable({
     ...              
});
```

**DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response.**

means the response, does not contain all the specified data. in your code, you have the following

```
          "columns": [
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "nif" },
                    { "data": "email" },
             ]
```

your response, needs to have name, nig and email defined.

example

```
...
$dataRes = [
  [
      "name" => "test name",
      "nif" => "test nif",
      "email" => "test email",
  ],
    [
        "name" => "test name",
        "nif" => "test nif",
        "email" => "test email",
    ],
];

$response = [
    'data' => $dataRes,
    'draw' => $_POST['draw'], // this is from your param
    'recordsFiltered' => sizeof($dataRes), // this is if your using search
    'recordsTotal' => sizeof($dataRes),
];
return $response
```

Comment: The question is here: if (request()->wantsJson())... the request is always JSON:NULL then doesn't enter there, where the response would be prepared.